# JerseyClient not throwing exception for 4xx and 5xx response

Tags: java, exception, jersey, client, resteasy

I have a jersey client which calls an api whose return type is javax.ws.rs.core.Response as defined in the interface being used.

```
public Response getResponse(String id)
```

The response for a call has status as 'Server Error' but the client does not throw InternalServerException rather returns InboundJaxrsResponse.

On checking Jersey code I see that the [JerseyInvocation](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyInvocation.java#L931) class being used has the logic to check if response type is of javax.ws.rs.core.Response then to return an InboundJaxrsResponse object.
How can I get an appropriate exception as per the response status here?

PS: [RestEasy](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/resteasy-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/internal/ClientInvocation.java#L481) client also has a similar logic.

Answer (score 2):

With presume that you use [`<T> T get(Class<T> responseType)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) to get integer from an HTTP response body, exception that can be thrown if response status is not 2xx is `WebApplicationException`.

In your case, the second requirement of API contract is not fulfilled

> `WebApplicationException` - in case the response status code of the
>   response returned by the server is not successful
>   **and the specified response type is not `Response`**.

Comment: I am using [JerseyClient](http://javadox.com/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.7/org/glassfish/jersey/client/class-use/JerseyClient.html). Is there a way to configure the client to throw WebApplicationException (if applicable) even when the response type is Response.

Comment: @nkr  As far as I know NO. `JerseyClient` is just an implementation, and must follow all rules of an interface